# Definite integral on fractional part

Tags: definite-integrals, fractional-part

Prove following definite integral:

$$\int_0^1\Bigl\{\frac{1}{x}\Bigr\}\ln(x)\,dx = \gamma_0+\gamma_1-1$$

Found in "Limits, Series, and Fractional Part Integrals: Problems in Mathematical Analysis" sample page (Problem Books in Mathematics, DOI 10.1007/978-1-4614-6762-5 2, © Springer Science+Business Media New York 2013) but not able to reach for the solution.

Also need if exist, a generalization on it noting that similar integral without logarithm on it retrieve $1-\gamma_0$.

Comment: Your question needs more context.  What are $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$?  What techniques do you know which you might be able to bring to bear?  What have you tried thus far?

Comment: Are there some results about integrals of the fractional part (or of the floor, so we can use $\{a\} = a - [a]$ to help) in the book that you might be expected to use?  Also, are $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$ [Stieltjes constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants)?  (Also, consider the general advice that you should explain what you have already tried.)

Comment: Yes $\gamma_k$ are Stieltjes constants. I only tried the hint suggestion substituing $y = 1/x$

Comment: Partial answer:  Using $y=\frac{1}{x}$, the integral becomes $-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_k^{k+1}\frac{(y-k)ln(y)}{y^2}dy.$.  I presume you can continue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\int_{0}^{1}\braces{1 \over x}\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x =
> \gamma_{0} + \gamma_{1} - 1:\ {\LARGE ?}}$ where
>   $\ds{\braces{\vphantom{\Large A}\gamma_{n}\ \mid\ n = 0,1,2,\ldots}}$ are 
>   [Stieltjes Constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants).
>   
>   $\ds{\gamma_{0}}$ is the
>   [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) too.

With $\ds{N \in \mathbb{N}_{\ \geq\ 1}}$:
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\braces{1 \over x}\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x &
\,\,\,\stackrel{x\ \mapsto\ 1/x}{=}\,\,\,
-\int_{1}^{\infty}\braces{x}\ln\pars{x}\,{\dd x \over x^{2}}
\\[5mm] & =
-\lim_{N \to \infty}\bracks{\int_{1}^{N}{\ln\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x -
\int_{1}^{N}\left\lfloor{x}\right\rfloor{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2}}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{N \to \infty}\bracks{\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{\sum_{k = 1}^{N - 1}k\int_{k}^{k + 1}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2}}\,\dd x}} - {1 \over 2}\,\ln^{2}\pars{N}}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

> Note that

\begin{align}
\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{\sum_{k = 1}^{N - 1}k\int_{k}^{k + 1}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2}}\,\dd x}} & =
\sum_{k = 1}^{N - 1}\bracks{\ln\pars{k} - \ln\pars{k + 1} + {1 \over 1 + k} +
{\ln\pars{1 + k} \over 1 + k}}
\\[5mm] & =
-\ln\pars{N} + H_{N} - 1 +
\sum_{k = 2}^{N }{\ln\pars{k} \over k}
\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}

> $\ds{H_{z}}$ is a *Harmonic Number*. \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} lead to:

\begin{align}
& \bbx{\int_{0}^{1}\braces{1 \over x}\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x} =
\\[5mm] = &\
\underbrace{\lim_{N \to \infty}\bracks{H_{N} - \ln\pars{N}}}
_{\ds{\gamma_{0}}}\ +\
\underbrace{\lim_{N \to \infty}\bracks{\sum_{k = 2}^{N}
{\ln\pars{k} \over k} -
{1 \over 2}\,\ln^{2}\pars{N}}}
_{\ds{\gamma_{1}}} - 1
\\[5mm] = &\ \bbx{\gamma_{0} + \gamma_{1} - 1}
\end{align}

> See the $\ds{\gamma_{1}}$ *definition* [in this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants#Representations).